# Can't find CSS to center my Wordpress lightboxes

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress, lightbox

Images on my web site, when opened in a lightbox (Lightbox Plus Colorbox plugin on Wordpress), are stubbornly appearing at the top left hand side of the screen, instead of at the middle. Any advice on this? I think something's overriding the Lightbox alignment -- it's meant to be centered automatically by default, and those default settings have worked in other web sites where I've used the plugin. I tried finding the source of the problem via Inspect Element, but I can't figure out what the issue is.

URL example: http://escape-industries.ninja/directions

Settings: All position settings are default. Full settings listed below.

Thanks!

~Ethan

WordPress Information

WordPress Version: 4.1
jQuery Version: 1.11.1
Server Information

Site URL: http://escape-industries.ninja
PHP Version: 5.3.29
Server Software: Apache
Plugin Information

Lightbox Plus Colorbox Version: 2.7
LBP Shortcode Version: 3.9
Colorbox Version: 1.5.9
Simple PHP HTML DOM Parser Version: 1.5 Rev: 202
Client Information

Browser: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_8) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36
Viewport: 1425x783
Platform: MacIntel
Javascript: Yes
Display Raw Settings
lightboxplus_multi: 0 | use_inline: 0 | inline_num: 5 | lightboxplus_style: dark | use_custom_style: 0 | disable_css: 0 | hide_about: 0 | output_htmlv: 0 | data_name: lightboxplus | load_location: wp_footer | load_priority: 10 | use_perpage: 1 | use_forpage: 1 | use_forpost: 0 | transition: elastic | speed: 0 | width: false | height: false | inner_width: false | inner_height: false | initial_width: 300 | initial_height: 100 | max_width: 80% | max_height: 80% | resize: 1 | opacity: 0.8 | preloading: 1 | label_image: | label_of: | previous: previous | next: next | close: close | overlay_close: 1 | slideshow: 0 | slideshow_auto: 0 | slideshow_speed: 500 | slideshow_start: start | slideshow_stop: stop | use_caption_title: 0 | gallery_lightboxplus: 1 | multiple_galleries: 1 | use_class_method: 0 | class_name: lbp_primary | no_auto_lightbox: 0 | text_links: 0 | no_display_title: 0 | scrolling: 1 | photo: 0 | rel: 0 | loop: 1 | esc_key: 1 | arrow_key: 1 | top: null | bottom: false | left: false | right: null | fixed: 0 |

https://wordpress.org/plugins/lightbox-plus/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your colorbox is initialized like

```
$("a[rel*=lightbox]").colorbox({
    speed:0,
    initialWidth:"300",
    initialHeight:"100",
    maxWidth:"80%",
    maxHeight:"80%",
    opacity:0.8,
    current:" {current}  {total}",
    top:"null",
    right:"null"
});
```

try removing the last two lines `top:"null",right:"null"`

final result should look like

```
$("a[rel*=lightbox]").colorbox({
    speed:0,
    initialWidth:"300",
    initialHeight:"100",
    maxWidth:"80%",
    maxHeight:"80%",
    opacity:0.8,
    current:" {current}  {total}"
});
```

or change `top:"null",right:"null"` to `top:false,right:false`